# Angular2 with ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, angular, gulp

I am playing around with Angular2 in combination with ASP.NET5, gulp and typescript. Everything works fine when I solve the tutorials for Angular, but I am not sure how to setup the process in combination with ASP.NET 5.

I made a project with working typescript compilation and bundling and I now the issues are starting:

1. When I add the tsConfig file to the root of the project, visual studio does not recognizes the file. When I place it to wwwroot/scripts everything is fine (very strange).
2. Angular2 does not support DefinityTyped anymore, the file is empty and contains the hint that I must install the npm package. I did it but there are so many files. Which type definitions do I have to include? None of them work. I always get the error that it cannot find *angular2/angular2*.
3. It is very strange. When I use commonjs for typescript the compilation works. I am really confused because I dont understand how the include works. Resharper shows a lot of errors but when I can disable it for the moment.
4. The Angular2 NPM Package also contains the script files. But because of the fact that they are outside I cannot reference them directly. I cannot find a bower package with the scripts and it also make no sense to have the package twice.

I would be quite happy about a tutorial or some best practices how to setup angular2 with asp.net 5.

By the way: There are so many package managers: NPM, NuGet, gulp, tsd...

Comment: Hi there, I am facing almost the same problems now.. Have you found answers / a tutorial yet? I am mostly interessted in your point 3 + 4. I would be thankful for any help :)

Comment: Yes, I have a second package.json in my wwwroot with the npm dependencies for the frontend. This works fine (you have to exclude the file from VS; otherwise it becomes VS becomes really slow). For bundling I use gulp-browserify. This works really well.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot! In the meantime, i found another interessting post: http://tattoocoder.azurewebsites.net/angular2-aspnet5-spa-template/ .

Answer (score 8):

I agree, it is somewhat bewildering at first to get Angular2 up and running in the Visual Studio Asp.net 5 environment.  I put the typescript files associated with my Angular2 app in a folder on the root called *App* (capital "A") and then use gulp to transpile into javascript into the "app" (small "a") at "./wwwroot/app".  The tsconfig.json file seems to function okay in the App folder and it looks like the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

My gulp task looks like the following (note that I also need to copy any associated HTML views and JSON files to the app folder as well):

```
var ts = require("gulp-typescript")
var tsProject = ts.createProject("./App/tsconfig.json");
gulp.task("compile:ts", function () {
    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(ts(tsProject));
    tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest("./wwwroot/app"));
    return gulp.src('./App/**/*.{html,json}')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/app'));
});
```

Now when I run the gulp task *compile:ts* my *app* folder gets all the proper assets.

Now, I realize you probably do not want to hear about yet another package manger, but I recommend you consider using JSPM.  Built by the same team that built system.js, JSPM really excels in bundling your Angular2 app for production. JSPM requires that you have a config.json file in your root and mine  (configured to tell JSPM where the angular2 dev dependencies are) is as follows:

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",
  paths: {
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "node_modules*": "node_modules/*"
  },

  packages: {
    "app": {
      "defaultExtension": "js"
    }
  },

  map: {
    "angular2": "node_modules/angular2",
    "bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6",
    "jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.1.4",
    "rxjs": "node_modules/rxjs",
    "ts": "github:frankwallis/plugin-typescript@2.4.3",
    "typescript": "npm:typescript@1.7.5",
    "github:frankwallis/plugin-typescript@2.4.3": {
      "typescript": "npm:typescript@1.7.5"
    },
    "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.6": {
      "jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.1.4"
    }
  }
});
```

The I use a gulp-jspm to execute the bundling into on self-contained js file:

```
var gulp_jspm = require("gulp-jspm");
gulp.task("jspm_bundle", ["compile:ts"], function() {
    return gulp.src("./wwwroot/app/bootApp.js")
        .pipe(gulp_jspm({ selfExecutingBundle: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./wwwroot/app-build/"));

});
```

Then into your index.html file you have one nice tidy script reference:

```
<script src="~/app-build/bootApp.bundle.min.js?v=@AppSettings.Value.BundleVersion"> </script>
```

When I build for production I change the BundleVersion variable as a cache buster.

Answer (score 4):

In relation to point #4, I believe that there are no plans to produce a Bower package for angular2 (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4018). This seems likely to cause some friction with Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET 5 template projects which are set up to use Bower for client-side packages (see http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/bower.html).

I have worked around this as follows:

1. Install the angular2 npm package: `npm install --save angular2`
2. Configure a gulp task to copy relevant files from the `node_modules` directory structure to the `wwwroot\lib` directory structure. This could be done as follows in `gulpfile.js`:

   ```
   /// <binding BeforeBuild='build-wwwroot-lib' />

   var gulp = require('gulp');

   var nodeModulesPath = './node_modules';
   var wwwrootLibPath = './wwwroot/lib';

   var libFiles = [
     nodeModulesPath + '/angular2/bundles/**',
     nodeModulesPath + '/es6-promise/dist/**',
     nodeModulesPath + '/es6-shim/es6-*',
     nodeModulesPath + '/reflect-metadata/Reflect*js',
     nodeModulesPath + '/rxjs/bundles/**',
     nodeModulesPath + '/zone.js/dist/**',
     /* ... Add other files required here as necessary ... */
   ];

   // Install relevant assets from node_modules to wwwroot/lib
   gulp.task('build-wwwroot-lib', function() {
     return gulp
       .src(config.lib, { base: nodeModulesPath })
       .pipe(gulp.dest(wwwrootLibPath));
   });
   ```

Comment: `config is not defined`, is it supposed to configure the extensions?