# How to deploy Angular 2 application developed in Typescript to production?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 2.  I am confused with how Angular 2 works in production environment.

1. What are the prerequisites for running Angular 2 application in production   server?
2. Is it possible to  deploy the application in IIS server or is node server required?
3. After compiling the file in development machine using node, do we need to deploy both .js and  .ts to production?

Answer (score 17):

I use JSPM to make my angular2 projects production ready.  Other popular tools like JSPM include webpack, and browserfy.  One of the important tasks that JSPM will accomplish is to bundle the various modules that make up your angular2 project.  I also set the "selfExecutingBundle" flag to true and have JSPM make one bundled js file (e.g. myApp.bundled.js) and from there I minify it (myApp.bundled.min.js) and this one script reference is used in the index.html file.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Hello Angular World</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</div>
    <script src="/js/myApp.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And that is all you need!

In the future when the HTTP/2 spec is more common, there may be less of a need to bundle your module-based projects, but for now I think bundling is needed.

There is no reference to your typescript files (as they were already transpiled in the process of making the myApp.bundled.js). As Zama said, you can run angular2 on any server (I use IIS and works fine).

UPDATE:  Since the final release of Angular 2, I have switched to using the angular-cli for building for production.  Setup is easy (no spaghetti of gulp tasks) and the final bundle is super-optimized (esp due to tree-shaking).  I recommend checking out the angular-cli for setting up, developing with, and building your ng2 projects.

Comment: Do you have a guide or something on how to bundle everything from typescript into a single file and minify it? I am trying to put my angular app into production for the first time ever. Since I am brand new to Typescript I don't know what a good approach is.

Comment: It can be a little tricky.  I have eloborated a bit more here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683885/angular2-with-asp-net-5/34495822#34495822   Drop me a line if you need more help.  Once configured it works like a charm.

Comment: I decided to just move my angular2 project over to: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter and it was actually quite painless to make single js files.

Comment: Hello brando. Since i am trying to follow your route and use JSPM to bundle everything into one js file i was wondering if you could share an example, maybe link to a git repository of an example project or something. There are so many new things to learn now, angular2,react,systemJS,typescript i find it to be overwhelming at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I run spring-boot+angular2.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Brankollic I elaborate a little bit more in this response:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614743/how-to-prepare-release-version-with-systemjs-and-gulp/34616199#34616199  Let me know if this help.  It can be a bit of a pain to get it right at first.

Comment: @brando yeah i have noticed your example, but i am still having major problems. I just cant seem to set up config file properly. Anyways was hoping you could post folder structure so i can "figure out" how you referenced what. Not to mention that i havent used gulp before, but i guess that really is not a problem. I can compile and bundle manually

Comment: Hi. I don't think it will work that simple. JSPM checks the dependencies on every systemJS module. In an angular application, you will always import things like "angular2/router" or "angular2/http". These modules cannot be found by JSPM.

Comment: @Vineet'DEVIN'Dev You can tell JSMP in the config.js file how to "map" the various dependent modules

Comment: @brando - How to do that? My angular.js file is being loaded from cdn as a system js module. But JSPM cannot find angular2 while bundling. I tried 'jspm bundle app/main build.js - angular2'. But this doesn't work!

Comment: @Vineet'DEVIN'Dev It won't work when you load from a cdn.  You have reference angular2 locally, then tell JSPM how to find dependencies.  I have an example here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34616199/3532945 and I only run EmbedTemplates when I am building for production

Answer (score 8):

Angular 2 applications are written in TS but the browser only understands JavaScript at the end. So any TS project is transpiled to JavaScript first event while development.

You can run angular 2 application on any server.

You only have to deploy .js files, since a browser won't parse .ts files.

Answer (score 3):

There are many starter seed projects that include the ability to serve and build your project.
I am using (and very happy with) https://github.com/antonybudianto/angular2-starter

You can find many others here:
https://github.com/timjacobi/angular2-education#boilerplates

Answer (score 3):

it's very simple to upload app on production. 
steps:

1. create an app using follow https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html
2. if your app has router then don't forget to use {useHash: true} for prevent the error can't load the page. like:

   RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
3. type npm build in your project root path.
4. it create dist folder automatically in project root directory.
5. don't need to setup node server on production. you can simply choose apache server and upload dist folder content.

Comment: Can you share more details on the last step? For example if I would like to use tomcat, what should I exactly copy to the webapps folder? and do I need to do some configurations? thanks a lot.

Comment: npm build command doesn't create a dist folder, what i'm missing?

Comment: @BingLu we don't need to require tomcat server. just configure apache server and paste the content. if you want to use tomcat server then make maven project and copy all data from dist folder to webapps folder in your project then deploy it.

Comment: @B.J.A.A. open package.json file then check build command in scripts array

Answer (score 3):

1. An application server (for my answer, I used Tomcat), node.js, and angular-cli (by running "`npm install -g angular-cli`")
2. You can deploy to other servers
3. Just .html, .js and .map files (at least for my solution)

This works better if you had created the application using angular-cli [instructions shown here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli#generating-and-serving-an-angular2-project-via-a-development-server). In your application root directory, run the following command `ng build --env=prod` and that will bundle, via webpack, the deployable items in the `\dist` directory.

Copy the `\dist` directory and paste it into `{CATALINA_HOME}\webapps`. Rename `\dist` to a folder name such as `\foo`. Open `\foo\index.html` and edit the base-href line to represent your new directory name:

```
<base href="/foo/">
```

Start Tomcat via startup.bat or your chosen preference and navigate to http://localhost:8080/foo/ and you should be able to view your Angular 2 application.

Note: If you had not created the project with `ng new` command, I had read where executing `ng init` before build will allow you to still follow the steps. I have not tested this myself though.

Answer (score 1):

All typescript files will be transpiled to js files while developing the application by the transpiler so you don't need ts files in production.

Also when you are done with the development , all you need to do is to make the bundle of `dist` directory using some bundling tool like `webpack-starter` or `angular2-seed`.

Then you deploy this bundle to your server.

The above mentioned packages have good amount of information on how one can deploy their angular2 app to production.

Hope this helps.