# To place an Angular2 page / app on a web server, what is the minimum set of files needed?

Tags: angular

If we follow the [quick start for Angular 2](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/README.md), there will be a set of files in the repository / working folder that is about 1.4MB, which we can upload to a web server.

However, if we consider uploading the `node_modules` folder installed by `npm install`, then it will be 200MB, which is not quite feasible.

The hosting company doesn't have `node` or `npm` to install the `node_modules`, but I think to deploy the angular2 app, it should not need `node` or `npm`.

With Angular 1.x, I think the minimum is 1 file, which is `index.html` with Angular code in it, and a single link to a CDN for `angular.js`

What is the minimum set of files that can deploy a simple Angular2 page / app onto a web server or hosting company?

Comment: See also http://www.ninjaducks.in/hacking/angular-setup/, http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular2-starter-walkthrough-overview/

Comment: This question could also interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407482/how-to-deploy-angular-2-application-developed-in-typescript-to-production.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the Angular application to get deployment files.

Comment: I cannot build it on my Mac and then upload to my hosting company?

Comment: so I think a simple way is just to use JSPM on my local machine and make all files into one `.js` file?

Comment: Something like that. There are different ways depending on how your project is set up.